# Реализация анимации

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Помогите пж, нужно сделать бесконечную анимацию, которая появляется на 3 сек, а потом исчезает на 5 сек и снова появляется, итак бесконечно. Как это можно реализовать через css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так, но чтобы указать явное время задержки Вам нужно указывать стили в самой анимации.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  animation: 5s rotit infinite;
}

@keyframes rotit {
  from {
    transform: rotatey(360deg);
  }
  66%,
  100% {
    transform: rotatey(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202702/delay-after-each-css-animation)

Comment: Не понял, что вы имеете в виду "Вам нужно указывать стили в самой анимации" то есть для того чтобы была задержка в конце анимации?

Comment: @Митяй, в анимации `rotit` указать моменты `66%, 100%` к примеру, чтобы вернуть блок в исходное положение и как-бы сделать "остановку"

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста:)